# How to save array of objects in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have this data from angular

```
 {
     "name": "Test name",
     "conditions": [
        {
         "id": "56a53ba04ce46bf01ae2bda7",
         "name": "First condition"             
        },
        {
         "id": "56a53bae4ce46bf01ae2bda8",
         "name": "Second condition"
        }
     ],
     "colors": [
        {
         "id": "56a545694f2e7a20064f228e",
         "name": "First color"
        },
        {
         "id": "56a5456f4f2e7a20064f228f",
         "name": "Second color"
        }
     ]
}
```

and I want to save this in ProductSchema in mongoDb but I don't know how to create schema for this

```
var ProductSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    conditions:  [Array],
    colors: [Array]
});
```

and how to save it to model in server controller

```
 var product = new Products({
    name: req.body.name,
    conditions: req.body.conditions,
    colors: req.body.colors
});
```

when I use this Schema and this controller I get empty record in collection except name and ObjectId. How to create right Schema and controller?

Comment: it's not an array of objects, it's just an object

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to create a mongoose model after you create your schema, and then you can save it. Try something like this:

```
var ProductSchema = new Schema({
name: String,
conditions:  [{}],
colors: [{}]
          });

var Product = mongoose.model('Product', productSchema);

var product = new Product({
    name: req.body.name,
    conditions: req.body.conditions,
    colors: req.body.colors
});

product.save( function(error, document){ //callback stuff here } );
```

Comment: Yes i did  but it seems to me it's wrong schema or error in     ` conditions: req.body.conditions,
    colors: req.body.colors` . I get in my collection saved name and objectId only . No conditions or colors.

Comment: Edited my answer.. I think you need to change the schema types for conditions and colors.

Comment: Worked for me,Thanks!

Comment: When I try to save it saves at 0th index but I have 2 elements here: 
services: "[{"service":  "A1", "price": "1000"}, {"service":  "A2", "price": "100..."

Comment: i have a question, when I add a new object to the conditions array is the previous values will be overwritten or it will just be added to the last of the array ?

Answer (score 1):

Of course, the above answer works, consider this as an **alternative**.

```
var defaultArray = ["A","B","C"];
var schemaDef = mongoose.Schema(       
  permission: { type: Array, default: defaultArray },
);
```